# Counting in subquery SELECT statement with WHERE and GroupBy

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am developing a webApp and I send filters towards my database in backend. I use mySql as a database. And what I would like to achieve is:

Counting how much messages where sent (count(mailId) from table)

Count how much of the sent message received a status(Status IS NOT NULL from table) . I dont know how to achieve this

taking the **GROUP BY** in mind

```
 SELECT formName
      , language
      , COUNT(mailid) AS totalsent
      ,  .... as totalfeedback 
   FROM mytable 
  WHERE formName in ('Z_4')
    AND language in ('F','N')
    AND sendingdate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' 
    AND returndate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' 
  GROUP 
     BY formName
      , language
```

Result can be for example:

```
formname   language     totalSent      FeedBackReceived
XXXX_Z984   F            9306              9120

XXXX_Z984  N           11337                 10500
```

This is my table:

```
     CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int(25) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `formName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sendingDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `telnumber` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `segment` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `returnDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `returnTime` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mailid_idx` (`mailId`) USING HASH,
  KEY `formname_idx` (`formName`),
  KEY `type_idx` (`mode`),
  KEY `language_idx` (`language`),
  KEY `email_idx` (`email`),
  KEY `status_idx` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=820396 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions like `count` take only non-null-values into account.

Thus, an expression like `count(status)` will count all non-null-values of attribute `status` in the respective group:

```
select formName, language, count(mailid) as totalsent, count(`status`) as totalfeedback 
FROM mytable 
where language in ('F','N')  
AND sendingdate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' 
AND returndate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30'
group by formName,language
```

If you additionally have to consider to count only those (non-null) `status`-values of records where `mailid` is not null, then you could write:

```
select formName, language, count(mailid) as totalsent, count(if(mailid is null, null, `status`)) as totalfeedback 
FROM mytable 
where language in ('F','N')  
AND sendingdate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30' 
AND returndate BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30'
group by formName,language
```